# Unambiguity of CBOR Diagnostic Notation: RFC8610, Appendix G.3

Tags: cbor

RFC 8610, appendix G.3 states the following:

> Where a byte string is to carry an embedded CBOR-encoded item, or
> more generally a sequence of zero or more such items, the diagnostic
> notation for these zero or more CBOR data items, separated by commas,
> can be enclosed in << and >> to notate the byte string resulting from
> encoding the data items and concatenating the result. For instance,
> each pair of columns in the following are equivalent:

```
  <<1>>              h'01'
  <<1, 2>>           h'0102'
  <<"foo", null>>    h'63666F6FF6'
  <<>>               h''
```

It is my understanding that the diagnostic notation refers to an encoding scheme where each element appearing between `<< >>` is first encoded to a byte array. Then, all the values are concatenated together. Furthermore, I have inspected implementations that seem to conform to the standard, and this is the be

**Question**: Is this encoding injective(non-ambigous)? Is it always the case that `<<a,b,c>>` will produce a different result than `<<a',b', c'>>` for instance? The values `a', b', c'` can be chosen arbitrarily(perhaps maliciously).

Comment: If that weren't the case, then CBOR sequences could not be deserialized. But [they can](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8742.html#section-2-6).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, thanks for the reply! After reviewing, I realized that I wasn't dealing with sequences themselves but with protocol specification that uses Cbor diagnostic notation. I have uèdated my question accordingly.

Comment: I think it's still the same question. A sequence of items enclosed in `<<...>>` is converted to a CBOR sequence, and that operation is injective.